# Chose the best sort key strategy for upserting in Redshfit

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-redshift, upsert

I need to daily perform [merges](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_updating-inserting-using-staging-tables-.html#merge-method-replace-existing-rows) on an event table which contains a primary key column (`pk`), a timestamp column (`timestamp`) and any other ones.

The upsert is performed the classical way:

1. copy file into a new `staging_table`;
2. delete from `main_table` where `pk` is in `staging_table`
3. insert in `main_table` everything from `staging_table`

The sort key is currently on the `timestamp` column for analytical purposes but as the table grows the merge operations are getting slower since it uses `pk` column in a `where` statement.

Do you have any recommendation to speed up my merge operations?

I was thinking about prefixing my `pk` column by the `timestamp` so `pk` and `timestamp` columns are sorted the exact same way.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: what percentage of your changes are logically updates, vs deletes, vs inserts? have you tried creating a new table instead? if that is faster you could implement a process switching between old and new using a/b type.

Comment: My `main_table` contains ~300M rows. A new file to be merged contains ~200K rows, among it insert/update/delete is 50/50/0%.